# Is AUC really cutoff independent?

Tags: r

I have tried to add some weights to the `FP`, `TN` in the `ROCR` package and evaluate the `Area Under the Curve AUC`.

Here is the code:

```
auc.tmp <- performance(pred,"auc",cost.fp=10, cost.tn=100); 
auc <- as.numeric(auc.tmp@y.values)
print(paste0("AUC is: ",auc))
```

and the output is:

```
"AUC is: 0.834187518842327"
```

Then i repeated the commands without the weights:

```
auc.tmp <- performance(pred,"auc"); 
auc <- as.numeric(auc.tmp@y.values)
print(paste0("AUC is: ",auc))
```

Again i received the same output as:

```
"AUC is: 0.834187518842327"
```

So, the output with cost and without cost are the same. When i refereed to the ROCR package manual, with  `?performance` about `auc` it is stated that:

### Since the output of auc is cutoff-independent, this measure cannot be combined with other measures into a parametric curve. The partial area under the ROC curve up to a given false positive rate can be calculated by passing the optional parameter fpr.stop=0.5 (or any other value between 0 and 1) to performance.

The result of codes verifies the ROCR manual claim, about indipendence of AUC output from cutoffs

But now let's look at this image.
A very basic interpretation is that, when i see the `TP` i go up, and when i see `FP` i go to left.
Therefore, **the area under the curve is hardly dependents on cutoffs?**

[image]

Comment: You need the whole curve to compute area under the curve, so those stepwise zigs and zags don't change the AUC. You would get different accuracy rates (e.g., sensitivity and specificity) at different points along the curve, but you can't compute AUC for a single point on the curve, because you don't have a curve.